# I want convert a listview to a recyclerview

Tags: listview, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-studio-3.0

I want to convert a list view to a recycler view. want to separate line adapter from user adapter. if possible how to do it, and please give sample code

mainActivity

```
public static class ChannelsSectionFragment extends Fragment {
        MainActivity mainActivity;

        public ChannelsSectionFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(@NonNull Activity activity) {
            mainActivity = (MainActivity) activity;
            super.onAttach(activity);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_channels, container, false);
            mainActivity.accessibilityAssistant.registerPage(rootView, SectionsPagerAdapter.CHANNELS_PAGE);

            ListView channelsList = rootView.findViewById(R.id.listChannels);
            channelsList.setAdapter(mainActivity.getChannelsAdapter());
            channelsList.setOnItemClickListener(mainActivity);
            channelsList.setOnItemLongClickListener(mainActivity);

            return rootView;
        }
    }
```

Adapter

```
class ChannelListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private static final int PARENT_CHANNEL_VIEW_TYPE = 0,
            CHANNEL_VIEW_TYPE = 1,
            USER_VIEW_TYPE = 2,
            INFO_VIEW_TYPE = 3,
            VIEW_TYPE_COUNT = 4;

        private final LayoutInflater inflater;

        Vector<Channel> subchannels = new Vector<>();
        Vector<Channel> stickychannels = new Vector<>();
        Vector<User> currentusers = new Vector<>();

        ChannelListAdapter(Context context) {
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        @Override
        public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
            subchannels.clear();
            stickychannels.clear();
            currentusers.clear();

            int chanid;
            if(curchannel != null) {
                chanid = curchannel.nChannelID;

                subchannels = Utils.getSubChannels(chanid, ttservice.getChannels());
                stickychannels = Utils.getStickyChannels(chanid, ttservice.getChannels());
                currentusers = Utils.getUsers(chanid, ttservice.getUsers());
            }
            else {
                chanid = ttclient.getRootChannelID();
                Channel root = ttservice.getChannels().get(chanid);
                if(root != null)
                    subchannels.add(root);
            }

            Collections.sort(subchannels, (c1, c2) -> c1.szName.compareToIgnoreCase(c2.szName));

            Collections.sort(stickychannels, (c1, c2) -> c1.szName.compareToIgnoreCase(c2.szName));

            Collections.sort(currentusers, (u1, u2) -> {
                if (((u1.uUserState & UserState.USERSTATE_VOICE) != 0) &&
                    ((u2.uUserState & UserState.USERSTATE_VOICE) == 0))
                    return -1;
                else if (((u1.uUserState & UserState.USERSTATE_VOICE) == 0) &&
                         ((u2.uUserState & UserState.USERSTATE_VOICE) != 0))
                    return 1;

                String name1 = Utils.getDisplayName(getBaseContext(), u1);
                String name2 = Utils.getDisplayName(getBaseContext(), u2);
                return name1.compareToIgnoreCase(name2);
            });

            super.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            int count = currentusers.size() + subchannels.size() + stickychannels.size();
            if ((curchannel != null) && (curchannel.nParentID > 0)) {
                count++; // include parent channel shortcut
            }
            return count;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {

            if (position < stickychannels.size()) {
                return stickychannels.get(position);
            }

            // sticky channels are first so subtract these
            position -= stickychannels.size();

            if (position < currentusers.size()) {
                return currentusers.get(position);
            }

            // users are first so subtract these
            position -= currentusers.size();

            if ((curchannel != null) && (curchannel.nParentID > 0)) {
                if(position == 0) {
                    Channel parent = ttservice.getChannels().get(curchannel.nParentID);

                    if(parent != null)
                        return parent;
                    return new Channel();
                }

                position--; // subtract parent channel shortcut
            }
            return subchannels.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {

            if (position < stickychannels.size())
                return INFO_VIEW_TYPE;

            // sticky channels are first so subtract these
            position -= stickychannels.size();

            if (position < currentusers.size())
                return USER_VIEW_TYPE;

            // users are first so subtract these
            position -= currentusers.size();

            if ((curchannel != null) && (curchannel.nParentID > 0)) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    return PARENT_CHANNEL_VIEW_TYPE;
                }

                position--; // subtract parent channel shortcut
            }

            return CHANNEL_VIEW_TYPE;
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return VIEW_TYPE_COUNT;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            Object item = getItem(position);

            if(item instanceof Channel) {

                final Channel channel = (Channel) item;

                switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
                    case PARENT_CHANNEL_VIEW_TYPE :
                        // show parent channel shortcut
                        if (convertView == null ||
                                convertView.findViewById(R.id.parentname) == null)
                            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_channel_back, parent, false);
                        break;

                    case CHANNEL_VIEW_TYPE :
                        if (convertView == null ||
                                convertView.findViewById(R.id.channelname) == null)
                            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_channel, parent, false);

                        ImageView chanicon = convertView.findViewById(R.id.channelicon);
                        TextView name = convertView.findViewById(R.id.channelname);
                        TextView topic = convertView.findViewById(R.id.chantopic);
                        Button join = convertView.findViewById(R.id.join_btn);
                        int icon_resource = R.drawable.channel_orange;
                        if(channel.bPassword) {
                            icon_resource = R.drawable.channel_pink;
                            chanicon.setContentDescription(getString(R.string.text_passwdprot));
                            chanicon.setImportantForAccessibility(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_YES);
                        }
                        else {
                            chanicon.setContentDescription(null);
                            chanicon.setImportantForAccessibility(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO);
                        }
                        chanicon.setImageResource(icon_resource);

                        if(channel.nParentID == 0) {
                            // show server name as channel name for root channel
                            ServerProperties srvprop = new ServerProperties();
                            ttclient.getServerProperties(srvprop);
                            name.setText(srvprop.szServerName);
                        }
                        else {
                            name.setText(channel.szName);
                        }
                        topic.setText(channel.szTopic);

                        OnClickListener listener = v -> {
                            if (v.getId() == R.id.join_btn) {
                                joinChannel(channel);
                            }
                        };
                        join.setOnClickListener(listener);
                        join.setAccessibilityDelegate(accessibilityAssistant);
                        join.setEnabled(channel.nChannelID != ttclient.getMyChannelID());

                        if (channel.nMaxUsers > 0) {
                            int population = Utils.getUsers(channel.nChannelID, ttservice.getUsers()).size();
                            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.population)).setText((population > 0) ? String.format("(%d)", population) : "");
                        }

                        break;

                    case INFO_VIEW_TYPE :
                        if (convertView == null ||
                                convertView.findViewById(R.id.titletext) == null)
                            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_info, parent, false);
                        TextView title = convertView.findViewById(R.id.titletext);
                        TextView details = convertView.findViewById(R.id.infodetails);
                        title.setText(channel.szName);
                        details.setText(channel.szTopic);
                        break;
                }
            }
            else if(item instanceof User) {
                if (convertView == null ||
                    convertView.findViewById(R.id.nickname) == null)
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_user, parent, false);
                ImageView usericon = convertView.findViewById(R.id.usericon);
                TextView nickname = convertView.findViewById(R.id.nickname);
                TextView status = convertView.findViewById(R.id.status);
                final User user = (User) item;
                String name = Utils.getDisplayName(getBaseContext(), user);
                nickname.setText(name);
                status.setText(user.szStatusMsg);
                
                boolean talking = (user.uUserState & UserState.USERSTATE_VOICE) != 0;
                boolean female = (user.nStatusMode & TeamTalkConstants.STATUSMODE_FEMALE) != 0;
                boolean away =  (user.nStatusMode & TeamTalkConstants.STATUSMODE_AWAY) != 0;
                int icon_resource;
                
                if(user.nUserID == ttservice.getTTInstance().getMyUserID()) {
                    talking = ttservice.isVoiceTransmitting();
                }
                if(talking) {
                    if(female) {
                        icon_resource = R.drawable.woman_green;
                        nickname.setContentDescription(getString(R.string.user_state_now_speaking, name) + " ");
                    }
                    else {
                        icon_resource = R.drawable.man_green;
                        nickname.setContentDescription(getString(R.string.user_state_now_speaking, name) + " ");
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if(female) {
                        icon_resource = away? R.drawable.woman_orange : R.drawable.woman_blue;
                        nickname.setContentDescription(name + " ");
                    }
                    else {
                        icon_resource = away? R.drawable.man_orange : R.drawable.man_blue;
                        nickname.setContentDescription(name + " ");
                    }
                }
                status.setContentDescription(away ? getString(R.string.user_state_away) : null);

                usericon.setImageResource(icon_resource);
                usericon.setImportantForAccessibility(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO);
                
                Button sndmsg = convertView.findViewById(R.id.msg_btn);
                OnClickListener listener = v -> {
                    if (v.getId() == R.id.msg_btn) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TextMessageActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent.putExtra(TextMessageActivity.EXTRA_USERID, user.nUserID));
                    }
                };
                sndmsg.setOnClickListener(listener);
                sndmsg.setAccessibilityDelegate(accessibilityAssistant);
            }
            convertView.setAccessibilityDelegate(accessibilityAssistant);
            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

I want to convert a list view to a recycler view. want to separate line adapter from user adapter. if possible how to do it, and please give sample code